# Odoo 13 import eCommerce categories

Tags: odoo-13

in odoo 13 I have a problem importing eCommerce categories (public categories). There is no Category Database ID option in the drop-down list. In this case, how can I make mass[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8wxT.png) changes to the categories. Or what I need to do to make the Category Database ID appear in the droplist. Thank you. I attach the image.

Answer (score 0):

For importing website categories you can pass full name in parent field. so full name of category is like  Root Category / Category 1 / Subcategory 2
so Root is top level category , Category 1 is under Root category and Subcategory 2 is child of Category 1. So arrange your excel or csv like order or hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` field is [hardcoded](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/base_import/models/base_import.py#L174) to match the external id.

The database id is available for [relational fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/base_import/models/base_import.py#L220). To pass the database id to the `parent_id` you will need to use `parent_id/.id` notation.

The following example creates a `courses` category with a parent category `Services` and two child categories `Sales & Marketing` and `Communication Skills` using the external id:

```
id;Display Name;parent_id/id
__export__.ecommerce_category1;Services;
__export__.ecommerce_category2;Courses;__export__.ecommerce_category1
__export__.ecommerce_category3;Sales & Marketing;__export__.ecommerce_category2
__export__.ecommerce_category4;Communication Skills;__export__.ecommerce_category2
```